# Bound on the size of a subset of a group give that there's an element $a$ such that $(xa)^3=1$ for all $x \in H$ (subgroup)

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, recreational-mathematics, problem-solving

Here's a problem I have been thinking about all day.

Let $H$ be a subgroup with $h$ elements of a group $G$. Suppose that $G$ has an element $a$ such that for all $x$ in $H$, $(xa)^3 = 1$, the identity. In $G$, let $P$ be the set of all products $x_1ax_2a \ldots x_n a$, with $n$ a positive integer and the $x_i$ in $H$. Show that $P$ has no more than $3h^2$ elements.

Here's is my attempt:

By setting $x=1$, we learn that $a^3=1$ and so $a=1$ or $\mathrm{ord}(a)=3$. Now if $a\in H$ then we are done since, $P\subset H$ whose order is at most $h$.

Hence, assume not and $\mathrm{ord}(a)=3$. Now we notice that $x_nax_na,\ldots,x_2ax_2a x_1ax_1a\in P$ is the inverse of $x_1ax_2a,\ldots,x_na$ and $1a1a1a=1\in P$. Therefore, $P$ is a subgroup of $G$.

At this point, I was hoping to use Lagrange's theorem to bound the order of $P$. I have tried many approaches but none of them led me anywhere meaningful.

I am hoping to get some hints. I prefer hints to complete solutions. Thank you for your time.

Comment: Is $G$ finite? ${} {} $

Comment: @MattSamuel Not necessarily. Does it help?

Comment: Lagrange's Theorem only applies to finite groups, so if you are not asusming that $G$ is finite then it cannot help you.

Comment: Lagrange theorem can only give a lower bound, it is useless here.

Comment: In the definition of $P$, the product must end with $a$ or with $x_n$?

Comment: @DerekHolt I should have been more explicit. I was trying to use Lagrange's theorem by showing $P$ is a subset of a finite subgroup. I failed frequently at finding elements that generate such group.

Comment: @user158834 they must end in $a$ sorry for the typo

Comment: Then your proof that $P$ is closed under taking inverses is wrong.

Comment: @user158834 that's also a typo. I will add $a$ right now

Comment: @user158834 Sorry, I don't understand your question. If I had $x_1ax_2a$, I am saying the inverse is $x_2ax_2ax_1ax_1a$ since $x_1ax_2a\cdot x_2ax_2ax_1ax_1a=x_2ax_2ax_1ax_1a\cdot x_1ax_2a=1$ using $(xa)^3=1$ property

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you want hints, this is not a complete solution.

Try to prove that every element of $P$ can be written as $xay$, $xa^{-1}y$, or $xa^{-1}ya$, with $x,y \in H$, thereby giving at most $3h^2$ elements.

Here is one step in the proof, to give you an idea.

Let $x,y,z \in H$. Then, using $(yza)^3=1$, we get  $(xay)(za) = x(yz)^{-1}a^{-1}(yz)^{-1}$.

Incidentally, arguments like this are used in the proof that finitely generated groups of exponent 3 are finite.

Comment: Thank you! This looks like what I'm looking for. I will work on it soon. If it is not going to spoil it for me, what's the underlying philosophy that made you look at these representations , −1, or −1?

Comment: As I said, it's similar to a proof that I know already about groups of exponents 3.